# jquery validation on phone numbers

Tags: jquery, validation, phone-number

Below is my current code. I need to make sure it always has the full phone number of Ten digits. Does anyone have the proper regex code? "US numbers"

```
"phone": {
    // credit: jquery.h5validate.js / orefalo
    "regex": /^([\+][0-9]{1,3}[ \.\-])?([\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\)])?([0-9 \.\-\/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$/,
    "alertText": "* Invalid phone number"
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");

$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      phoneUS: true
    }
  }
});
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see: [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123559/900747) for more comprehensive answers. But, I think that this is the Regex that you want:

```
^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$
```

Comment: it will accept 1 number only. So as long as when someone fills out the form and puts in a single digit it allows them to move forward. I want to make sure they put in the full 10 digit US phone number.